# Creating a Class Hierarchy with no Public Attributes

Tags: inheritance, abstract, getter

I am working on a practice exam question that asks me to build a Battery hierarchy with only private attributes, and no re-declaration of attributes. I have four classes, Battery, BadBattery(an exception class), SingleUse, and Rechargeable. I know that Battery should be an abstract class, which is why I'm confused as to why I can't declare the attributes of this class to be public. I got my hierarchy to give the exact output that my professor wanted, but if I'm to make the attributes private in my abstract class, how can I avoid having to re-declare them in any of the child classes? Would I have to have a bunch of public getters in my abstract class so that I can access those attributes in any child classes?

Answer (score 0):

Using inheritance, the only way to not re-declare variables in common to all subclasses, hiding them to the rest of the context, is declare these as `protected` in the base class (it doesn't matter if it is abstract or concrete).
 In this way, the attributes can be directly accessed to the class hierarchy, the rest of the world can access only using `public` **getters** .